# Why do I get "Illegal generic type for instanceof"?

Tags: java, generics

Given:

```
public class C<T> {
    private class D {
        public boolean equals( Object o ) {
            if ( !(o instanceof D) )    // line 4
                return false;
            D other = (D)o;             // line 6
            return i == other.i;
        }
        int i;
    }
}
```

I get:

```
C.java:4: illegal generic type for instanceof
          if ( !(o instanceof D) )
                              ^
```

I also get an "unchecked cast" warning about line 6.  Why?  The `o` is *not* a generic type -- it's just a plain `Object`.  How can I correctly implement `equals()` by both checking for and casting to an instance of `D`?

Note: Obviously, this code example is a whittled-down version of my actual code.  The real classes for `C` and `D` are much larger and `D` is a `private` inner class of `C` used by its implementation.

FYI: The real `D` does make use of the generic parameter `T`.

Comment: Have you tried *instanceof C.D* instead of *instanceof D*?

Comment: I'm just going to note that the example given *is* broken.

Comment: @Evan: That works.  But why is qualification necessary?

Comment: This may be a compiler bug (http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5300129).

Comment: @Evan: Great link -- thanks!  But I don't think it's a bug if you read through all the comments... just a bizarre consequence of Java generics.

Comment: You may be correct, I just got to that part: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10272417#10272417

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> The o is not a generic type -- it's just a plain Object.

That's not the problem.  The problem ... and the root cause of both compilation errors ... is that `D` is a generic class.  And it is generic because it is a non-static nested class in a generic class.  Its fully qualified name would be `some.pkg.C<T>.D`.

> FYI: The real D does make use of the generic parameter T.

And the fact that it *could* make use of `T` is what makes `D` a generic class.

The reason that you cannot use `instanceof D` or `(D)` is generic type erasure.  Basically, the runtime cannot distinguish between the types of (say) `C<String>.D` and `C<Integer>.D`.  And since it cannot do that, it cannot determine if `instanceof D` should return `true` or `false` or if `(D)` should succeed or throw `ClassCastException`.

One solution would be to declare `D` as static.  But that will not work with your "real D" because a static class cannot make use of a generic type parameter from the enclosing class(es).  Your "FYI" says that it does that.

Another solution is to instantiate the outer class `C` passing it the actual type of `T` as a `java.lang.Class<T>` instance.  Then use this `Class` instance to implement the runtime type checks and casts as required.  This is likely to be messy.

The third solution is to *carefully* analyze the code and determine if it is safe to a @SuppressWarning annotations to suppress the "unsafe cast" etc warnings.

> What type erasure? 'o' is of type Object directly.

Actually `Object` is the *declared* type of the `o` variable.  The actual object will most likely have some other type, and it is *that* type that (if it is a `D` instance for example) will have been subjected to type erasure.

Answer (score 14):

@StephenC is right in that the problem is that `D` means `C<T>.D`, which is a parameterized type. The solution is to use the raw type or the wildcard-parameterized type:

```
if ( !(o instanceof C.D) )
```

or

```
if ( !(o instanceof C<?>.D) )
```

Answer (score 7):

If you make the inner class static, the code compiles fine.

Ex:

```
private static class D{...}
```

Read [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for the difference.

You could also try `o.getClass() != D.class` (after guarding against o being null, of course)

Comment: I know the difference between non-static and static nested classes.  In this case, I need it non-static.  If I make the nested class static, I can't make use of the generic parameter T.

Comment: What about o.getClass() and D.class comparisons? You won't know that they're of the same parameterized type, but I'm not sure you can reliably do that anyway with type erasure.

Comment: What type erasure?  'o' is of type Object directly.

Comment: Supposing 'o' is pointing at some type D<K>, there's no way to tell that it's a D<K> and not a D<L>. So if I'm a D<L> and o is really a D<K>, the best you can say is that they're both a D.

Comment: But it's a plain Object which could be *any* object: D<K>, Integer, Runnable, etc.  I don't understand why the type matters.

Answer (score 6):

```
D.class.isInstance(o)
```

seems to work here.